# Where I can find firebase custom analytics event values

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, custom-dimensions

Where I can find Firebase analytics custom event values?
I have a search event with search-inputted text.
I want to see what people searched for.
My code is the following:

```
  await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(
              name: "SEARCH_EVENT",
              parameters: {"search_term": inputtedText},
            );
```

But I cannot find what things people searched for.
I've added custom metrics and dimensions, but nothing works.

[image]

Dimensions:
[image]